# How expect toMatch works?

Tags: playwright

I'm doing a POC with playwright with {expect} from '@playwright/test'.

I'm a bit confused how to create the regexp, I expect to validate this string which is correct as per the regex validator.
`expect('abc123').toMatch('abc(\d+)')`

first the '\' is marked as Unnecessary escape character 
tried '\\' marks error 
removed '\' marks error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`toMatchText`](https://elaichenkov.github.io/playwright-expect/modules/tomatchtext.html):

```js
import { expect } from '@playwright/test';

await expect('abc123').toMatchText(/abc\d+/);
```

I don't see `toMatch` in the docs, so I used `toMatchText()`. I also think that capturing group in the regex `()` is not necessary in this example, so `\d+` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you! although I do not see .toMatchText() it worked  with your regexp; I'm using cucumber and playwright 1.16,

Answer (score 0):

```
import { expect } from '@playwright/test';
    
let pattern = new RegExp('abc(\d+)');
const text = await page.locator('.label').textContent();
expect(text).toEqual(expect.stringMatching(pattern));
```

On this example you can receive a Regular Expression parameter as string and converted to a RegExp object, hence backlashes are not explicitly necessary.

Then compare with a text with `expect.stringMatching` as shown in the last row

Answer (score 0):

`toMatch` in Playwright is actually re-exported from jest, so it should works as totally same as [`toMatch` in jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchregexp--string).

Also, I quoted [the most important source code of this matcher](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/4ecf91ccb26f012f76b4d3a758f5b205590d5488/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts#L844C1-L847) for you, you may have a look at it.

In conclusion, it will test the received value if you give a regular expression as expected value, or it will try to identify whether the received value contains expected value if the expected value is a string.

*Note: the received value is the parameter of `expect`, and the expected value is the parameter of `toMatch`.*